# Need help finding name of function

Tags: c#, java, function, encryption

My friend sent me an encoded string which I would assume is Java or C#, but since I code in neither of them I could need some help. The string is as follows:

```
0x579fb13
```

I thought about it being base 64 or so at first, but the 0x indicates it's hex or something.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: It is a 7 byte hex (91880211). So, what would you like help with?

Comment: How did you manage to decode it, abhinav? I read about decoding hex values without any luck, also tried several online decoders. Any function I can use or tutorial how to do it?

Answer (score 3):

The `0x` would indeed normally indicate that it's hex. That looks like a memory location to me, and as such may be (inadvertently) the pointer to the structure containing the encrypted string.